# How do I write a number to a file in python whilst removing the original number from the file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that adds 1 to a number it receives from a file and then writes this new integer to the same file replacing the original value.
I have this so far:

```
import linecache
averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "a")
averagenumber = linecache.getline("trackerofquiz.txt", 1).rstrip("\n")
print(repr(averagenumber))# to check if it has any strings 
averagenumber = int(averagenumber)#these 4 lines get the number from the quiztracker for the
averagenumber = averagenumber + 1 #average, turns it into an int, adds 1 then turns it back to
averagenumber = str(averagenumber)#an str, not sure if you need to turn it back into an str 
print(repr(averagenumber))# to check if it has any strings 
averagetracker.write(averagenumber)
averagetracker.close()
print("success")
```

whenever I do it, it works but it doesn't remove the original value, so if I start with "0" and run it it will be written to the file as "01". Re-running it then uses "01" and adds 2 on the end of it giving "012" and so on with the same logic.How can I make it so that it removes the value it received from the file so that value doesn't intervene ?
Thanks.

Comment: instead of "a" argument for your open function, you'd have to use "r+". "a" means append, so you can only write to the end of the file. "r+ will let you seek to a position and write anywhere in the file

Comment: Umm... there's no iteration in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "a")` to `averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "r")`. Then, just before the `averagetracker.write(averagenumber)` line, write `averagetracker.close()` and `averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "w")`.

It should look like this:

```
import linecache
averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "r")
averagenumber = linecache.getline("trackerofquiz.txt", 1).rstrip("\n")
print(repr(averagenumber))# to check if it has any strings 
averagenumber = int(averagenumber)#these 4 lines get the number from the 
quiztracker for the
averagenumber = averagenumber + 1 #average, turns it into an int, adds 1 then turns it back to
averagenumber = str(averagenumber)#an str, not sure if you need to turn it back into an str 
print(repr(averagenumber))# to check if it has any strings 
averagetracker.close()
averagetracker = open("trackerofquiz.txt", "w")
averagetracker.write(averagenumber)
averagetracker.close()
print("success")
```

This is because the 'a' signifies 'append' (write to end of file) whereas 'w' refers to 'write' (replace contents of file). However, you cannot start with 'w' as this will instantly erase the contents of the file (from the program's perspective) so you need to start with 'r' (read) and then open it again with 'w' afterwards.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but that works, thankyou! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `open("trackerofquiz.txt", "a")` you've indicated that you want to append to your file (the "a").  To overwrite the file change the "a" to "w" and you should be golden.

Comment: I tried that before and I got this error message: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: When python opens files to write to them it clears everything that was on the file before meaning there isn't anything left on the file.

Comment: As Alto Allas pointed out in the other answer - which is correct and mine is wrong - "w" deletes the data before it's read.